# IMEI in Unity for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, imei

Can i find the IMEI for Android in **Unity**?

I found an example for the Android_ID for **Unity**:

```
AndroidJavaClass up = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = up.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
AndroidJavaObject contentResolver = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("getContentResolver");  
AndroidJavaClass secure = new AndroidJavaClass ("android.provider.Settings$Secure");
string android_id = secure.CallStatic<string> ("getString", contentResolver, "android_id");
```

Can i find the IMEI with this method and modify this code??

I found also the code in **Eclipse** to find the IMEI code.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String IMEI = tm.getDeviceId();
```

Who can help?
Thank you!

Comment: _"and modify this code?"_ You mean change the IMEI of your device..? Apps aren't allowed to do that.

Comment: No, i mean modify the code where you "calculate" the Android_ID to fiund the IMEI :)

Answer (score 2):

On Android you can get the phone's IMEI [by using](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html)

```
string imei = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;
```

Note that this requires the [android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE) to be set to true. If this permission is not available, the identifier will be a different one.

Answer (score 1):

```
AndroidJavaObject TM = new AndroidJavaObject("android.telephony.TelephonyManager");

string IMEI = TM.Call<string>("getDeviceId");
```