# unity get phone data: iphone/android

Tags: c#, android, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in unity and I want to get the data of the people who installed my game.
With regular android apps I can do it easly in android studio by just asking for permissions and send the relevant data to an online server.

But I have no idea how to do it with C# and unity. can you give me any help please?

And also some hints on how to do it wit iphone.

Thank you.

Comment: What type of data?

Comment: phone book, phone's number, IMEI or IMSI number, those stuff that you can get easly with android studio. But I don't know how to do it with C#.

Answer (score 0):

right now there is no unity solution for that and you need to write some android native code for that

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can do this:

```
var deviceIMEI = "";
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        AndroidJavaObject TM = new AndroidJavaObject("android.telephony.TelephonyManager");
        deviceIMEI = TM.Call<string>("getDeviceId");
#endif
```

[Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22299832/12722969)